# Same class in multiple files

Tags: c++

Just for some practice, I'm looking at the different ways classes can be used within C++.

I've created the following project, which all I want to do is simply just ensure the same 'instance' of a class is being used across the project.

For example, I have `main.cpp` which has basic functionality which allows the user to set their health value. In `path_one.cpp`, I want to call the same class and display the same value as it does in `main.cpp`.

Here is the code for each file;

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "player_class.h"
#include "path_one.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int set_health;
    Player player;
    cout << "Your Health is: " << player.health;

    cout << "\nSet your health:  ";
    cin >> set_health;
    player.health = set_health;
    cout << "Your Health is now: " << player.health;

    path_one();

    return 0;
}
```

player_class.h

```
#pragma once


class Player
{
public:
    int health;
    int attack;
    int strength;
    int defence;

    Player()
    {
        health = 0;
        attack = 0;
        strength = 0;
        defence = 0;
    }
};
```

path_one.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "player_class.h"
#include "path_one.h"
using namespace std;

void path_one() 
{
    Player player;

    printf("\n\nYour Health is: %d", player.health);
}
```

path_one.h

```
#pragma once
#include "player_class.h"
#include "player_class.h"


void path_one();
```

Once the 'Health' is set, and then goes into the `path_one();`, is to have it display the same value for health, rather than 'redefine' the class and display 0.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: might the singleton pattern help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance of player on path_one.cpp is local and it will be seen only in this function.

To all path_one calls see the same Player instance, you need to pass it by reference:

```
void path_one(Player& player) {
    printf("\n\nYour Health is: %d", player.health);
}
```

You can create a singleton that is nothing more than a static instance of Player, but it is not recommended because in the end of day, singleton create unnecessarily structure to global variables and functions that you can better replace with namespaces definitions. Will get a more clear, simple and better code.

Comment: This makes sense, passing it by reference. In ```main.cpp```, calling the function requires an argument to passed into it, i've passed in 'player'm but I get an error about unresolved external symbols.

Comment: That strange because it is a common use. Maybe you miss something like adjust the function description at header file (path_one.h) or didn't delete the local instance creation of Player at path_one function

Comment: Ah, I just spotted the mistake. Forgot to removed 'static' from a variable name, but it's working perfectly. Thank you! :)

Comment: @George_H How are you compiling your program? If you are not using an IDE but are compiling things by hand, you will have a very hard time with C++. You need to compile all source files separately and then link the resulting object files into an executable. An IDE will do this automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Tow different objects of the type Player with the automatic storage duration are created in the function main and path_one.

Objects of the same class can share their static data members.

So if the data member `health` would be declared with the storage specifier static

```
static int health;
```

then you would get the expected result that the both functions deal with the same object health.

Do not forget to defined the static data member outside the class in some cpp file. For example

```
int Player::helth;
```

Otherwise you need one object with the external linkage that will be accessed in main and path_one.

For example in the header you could declare

```
extern Player player;
```

and then in one of cpp files define it

```
Player player;
```

If the compiler supports C++ 17 then you could in the header just write

```
inline Player player;
```

Comment: I did try this, but I got errors about unresolved external symbols.

Comment: @George_H If you make the health static, then all players you create will all share the same health. I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: @George_H If I have understood correctly you forgot to define the static data member outside the class definition.